# How to calculate ScreenToWorld coordinates?

Tags: c++, glm-math

I have an object that contains my view state, and I wish to be able to convert from world to screen coordinates, which works. However I also want to be able to convert from screen to world coordinates, I have the following code:

```
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>

class CoordinateSpace
{
public:
   CoordinateSpace(int w, int h)
   {
       mW = w;
       mH = h;
   }

   glm::vec2 WorldToScreen(const glm::vec2& worldPos)
   {
     return ((mProjection * mView) * glm::vec4(worldPos, 1, 1)) * glm::vec4(mW / 2, -mH / 2, 1, 1) + glm::vec4(mW / 2, mH / 2, 0, 0);
   }


    glm::vec2 ScreenToWorld(const glm::vec2& screenPos)
    {
       return (glm::inverse(mProjection * mView) * glm::vec4(screenPos, 1, 1)) * glm::vec4(mW / 2, -mH / 2, 1, 1) + glm::vec4(mW / 2, mH / 2, 0, 0);
    }

    void UpdateCamera()
    {
        glm::mat4 target_projection = glm::ortho(
            -mScreenSize.x / 2.0f, 
            mScreenSize.x / 2.0f, 
            mScreenSize.y / 2.0f, 
            -mScreenSize.y / 2.0f, 
            -1.0f,
            1.0f);

        glm::mat4 camMat = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(-mCameraPosition, 0));
        mView = camMat;
        mProjection = target_projection;
    }

    glm::vec2 mScreenSize = glm::vec2;
    glm::vec2 mCameraPosition = glm::vec2;

protected:

    int mW = 0;
    int mH = 0;

    // 2d ortho projection
    glm::mat4 mProjection;

    // camera location into the world
    glm::mat4 mView;
};

TEST(CoordinateSpace, Conversion)
{
    CoordinateSpace coords(640, 480);
    coords.mCameraPosition = { 0.0f, 0.0f };
    coords.mScreenSize = { 640.0f, 480.0f };
    coords.UpdateCamera();

    const glm::vec2 actual1 = coords.WorldToScreen({ 50.0f, 100.0f });
    ASSERT_EQ(glm::round((640.0f/2)+50.0f), glm::round(actual1.x));
    ASSERT_EQ(glm::round((480.0f/2)+100.0f), glm::round(actual1.y));

    const glm::vec2 actual2 = coords.ScreenToWorld(actual1);
    ASSERT_EQ(glm::round(50.0f), glm::round(actual2.x));
    ASSERT_EQ(glm::round(100.0f), glm::round(actual2.y));
}
```

Instead of `50.0f` I get `5.12032e+06`, how do I correctly calculate `ScreenToWorld`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have:

SCREENPOS = ((PROJ * VIEW) * WORLDPOS) * A + B;

Using algebra to isolate WORLDPOS, I'd presume this would work:

WORLDPOS = ((SCREENPOS - B) / A) * INV(PROJ*VIEW)

SO:

return glm::inverse(mProjection * mView) * ((screenPos - glm::vec4(mW / 2, mH / 2, 0, 0)) / glm::vec4(mW / 2, -mH / 2, 1, 1));

Comment: Had to use `return glm::inverse(mProjection * mView) * ((glm::vec4(screenPos.x ,screenPos.y, 1, 1) - glm::vec4(mW / 2, mH / 2, 0, 0)) / glm::vec4(mW / 2, -mH / 2, 1, 1));` to keep the type system happy, thanks!